# Apache not sending headers on certain SSL errors

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http

If I make a http:// request over port 443 on our server, Apache is sending a plaintext error page with no headers, which most implementations of the protocol will interpret as a 200/

As far as I can tell it's this bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50823 - which has been fixed in the trunk, but there isn't a release for it yet.

Are there any workaround for it, as it's causing me headaches - to be honest, the simple solution of dropping http-over-403 would be perfect, but I don't know how/if it can be done?

Example of what I am seeing: http://www.absolute-server.co.uk:443/asdasd/

Comment: So far I've tried:

-Custom error pages (shows the custom page, but still without headers)
- Using mod_rewrite to look for connections on the 443 vhost but where https is off (still just displays default error page)

Right now I'm struggling!